# Mocking the number in url in axios in ReactJS

Tags: regex, reactjs

I was working on the React project. I wanted to mock the service call. I wanted to mock the number part. I wanted to do the mock the service call using the Axios. Can anyone help me to solve this?

This is how I mocked the service call. It is working when the service is /abc/101/efg/341.

```
mock.onGet('/abc/101/efg/341').reply(200, hij);
```

I wanted the service call work for all the mock values in this format:
/abc/{any number}/efg/{any number}.

I am not getting which regiular exoression to be used?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use template-strings instead of regex?

```
mock.onGet(`/abc/${Math.floor(Math.random()*1000)}/efg/${Math.floor(Math.random()*1000)}`).reply(200, hij);
```

Comment: I wanted to mock for all numbers thats why I used regular expressions. But  this is not working also. I prefer the way of using regular expression to mock it. It will look good.

Answer (score 0):

i like using moxios https://github.com/axios/moxios,
You can use regex as URL for testing

```
moxios.stubRequest("/abc/[0-9]+/efg/[0-9]+")
```

Hope it can help you

Comment: post your test i will  help you after